# Migrating datbase using SQLC from Docker not working

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, makefile, sqlc

I am trying to generate database migrations using [SQLC](http://sqlc.dev) over Windows OS. According to the [official documentation](https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/stable/overview/install.html#docker) I need to run the Docker command (because it supports Postgres over Windows).

If I run `docker run --rm -v "${pwd}:/src" -w /src kjconroy/sqlc generate` from a CLI it works. But if I run `make sqlc` it displays an error:

> docker run --rm -v ":/src" -w /src kjconroy/sqlc generate
>
> error parsing configuration files. sqlc.yaml or sqlc.json: file does not exist
>
> make: *** [Makefile:12: sqlc] Error 1

I have my folder structure like this:

- app/

  - db/

    - migration/
    - query/

      - myquery.sql
    - sqlc/
  - sqlc.yaml
  - Makefile

My `sqlc.yaml` file has this:

```yaml
version: "1"
packages:
    - name: "db"
      path: "./db/sqlc"
      queries: "./db/query"
      schema: "./db/migration/"
      engine: "postgresql"
      emit_json_tags: true
      emit_prepared_queries: false
      emit_interface: false
      emit_exact_table_names: false
```

And `Makefile` this:

```
sqlc:
    docker run --rm -v "${pwd}:/src" -w /src kjconroy/sqlc generate

.PHONY: sqlc
```

So, how to make it work from the Makefile? I am not getting the error here? Maybe the field mapping is wrong?

Comment: I'd guess that `"${pwd}` is not evaluating to what you expect (either `make` is attempting to expand it, or its just not resolving to the `db` folder); [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71760845/11810946) might help. Please let us know which implementation of make you are using.

Comment: @Brits, thank you. `${CURDIR}` made the trick. Just answer that so I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `sqlc.yaml or sqlc.json: file does not exist` simply means that `sqlc` (running in a container) is not finding the `sqlc.yaml` file in `/src`. When starting the container you are mapping `${pwd}` to `/src` so the issue is that `${pwd}` is not evaluating to the `app/db` folder as you expect it to. This is could be due to either:

- Make attempting to expand it (see [GNU Make docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html#Reference) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71760845/11810946)) or,
- Its just not resolving to the db folder

In your case (based on your comment) it's the former and changing `${pwd}` to `${CURDIR}` fixes the issue.